# OpenCV stereoRectify

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

If I have already computed the intrinsics(Camera matrix and distortion coefficients) in the lab.

I have then moved the cameras out in the real world field.
I used about 6-10 known locations in the real world, to estimate the camera pose using SolvePnP(). So I also have the two cameras rotation and translation.

I now want to use the 2 cameras to create a stereoCorrespondence.
Question is:
Do I have to use stereoCalibrate()?

Or can I call StereoRectify right away, using the already known intrinsics?
It says StereoRectify() expects a rotation and translation vector/matrix,
The documation says it expects:

```
"The rotation matrix between the 1st and the 2nd cameras’ coordinate systems."
```

Since I have the camera pose of both cameras, can I simply subtract the 2 translation-vectors and rotation vectors I got from SolvePnP, and pass the result to StereoRectify()?
(Both cameras use the same common object-point reference system)

Comment: You need not do stereo calibrate I presume...coz you have the translation and rotational vecs...

Comment: I would imagine so, though I have never tried it.  Just make sure you keep track of which camera is "1st" and "2nd" its easy to get mixed up when you subtract vectors like that

Comment: I am in the exact same situation , can you please share what was you next step? I am getting camera parameters from Android APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calibrating the cameras to the world (e.g. your known locations) is different from calibrating them in respect with each other. In your case you can subtract the translation vectors. This will give you the translation from one camera to the other (provided you calibrated them with the same fixed point). You can also obtain the inter-camera rotation matrix, but this can't be done by simply subtracting them, you need more complicated math. That's why I'd advise you to use stereo calibration provided by opencv.

Comment: Why won't it work to subtract the rotation-vectors as well?
I do indeed use the same reference model with same point of origin, for both cameras for SolvePnP().
It gives me a rotation-vector in the form of (X,Y,Z) saying how much to rotate along the X,Y and Z axis. So Can't i just subtract this 2 rotation-vectors, then make a rotation-matrix of the end result?

Comment: A rotation can be described in [many ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) Of course if you have two vectors (in respect to the same point of origin) you can subtract them. But a rotation vector in Euler angles notation, is not a 3-d vector that points somewhere. Actually is an axis around which a rotation is performed.

Comment: From the above article in wikipedia _Combining two successive rotations, each represented by an Euler axis and angle, is not straightforward, and in fact does not satisfy the law of vector addition, which shows that finite rotations are not really vectors at all. It is best to employ the rotation matrix or quaternion notation, calculate the product, and then convert back to Euler axis and angle._